# Arch Linux dosen't go over bootloader after update

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, bootloader, syslinux

I have Archlinux with encrypted HDD and updated my system after 1-2 weeks.
Then, after the update I wasn't able to boot again.
The system is entering the bootloader, syslinux, and after that when I choose what to boot syslinux is resetting it's state, with that I mean the time is starting again which you have to what you want to boot.
But I didn't get any errors.

The updates including a linux update, the new image was createt from pacman before.
Ive already tried to create the image by myself while rootet in the system but thats the same result.

Any suggestions or something I've missed?

Update:

I've installed my boot partition again, made a new GPT-Table and formatted to ext4.

Now syslinux is booting and decrypting my hdd, but while the boot process he is unable to mount /boot, wrong fs type, bad option or bad superblock on this partition, anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got to manage the problem.
The main problem was that the initramfs image was broken, so I had to generate a new image and somehow my boot partition got broken, so I had to create it again.